# Smooth div scroll not working when toggle is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a div that contains content from a database. All of the divs use the same class as they loop with different content being echoed into them via php. I would like to use Smooth Div Scroll and am able to get it working just fine (see Fiddle), but once I add the script below, which allows the div to be hidden until another div is clicked, it does not work. How can I use both scripts?

http://jsfiddle.net/2Hr4U/549/

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".flip").click(function(){
            $(this).siblings(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please note I do not have .panel set to `display:none;` in the fiddle so you guys can see how it initially works. And lastly, obviously the div content in the fiddle is not echoing php-- my original looks more like this: `<?php echo $name; ?>` but you catch the general idea.

***UPDATE***
Works great in fiddle, not on my test page- therein lies the conflict.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2Hr4U/556/ or is this not right?

Comment: that's weird, yes it is working. Thanks!

Comment: The conflict seems to be in the ordering of the rest of the javascript on my page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/2Hr4U/561/

```
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

You essentially want to use `.next()` instead of `.siblings()`. Another way would be to use a class name for both your flip link and your panel and tie them together. That way you won't have to worry about positioning of the panel next to the link to click.